# Kotlin Spring cannot register bean in application context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Hello I am a Kotlin and Spring newbie who is trying to register a named bean to application context as shown in [Spring 5 Functional Bean Registration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-functional-beans.). However, the function signature does not match. Any helps are appreciated. I get the following error: 
[Function signature error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn2V0.jpg)

Here is the text version of the error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public final fun <T : Any!> registerBean(p0: Class<(???..???)>, p1: () -> (???..???), p2: Array<(out) BeanDefinitionCustomizer!>): Unit defined in org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext
public final fun <T : Any!> registerBean(p0: Class<(???..???)>, p1: Supplier<(???..???)>, vararg p2: BeanDefinitionCustomizer!): Unit defined in org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext
public final fun <T : Any!> registerBean(p0: Class<(???..???)>, vararg p1: BeanDefinitionCustomizer!): Unit defined in org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext
public open fun <T : Any!> registerBean(@Nullable p0: String?, p1: Class<Long!>, @Nullable p2: Supplier<Long!>?, vararg p3: BeanDefinitionCustomizer!): Unit defined in org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext
public final fun <T : Any!> registerBean(@Nullable p0: String?, p1: Class<Long!>, vararg p2: BeanDefinitionCustomizer!): Unit defined in org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext
```

Here is the code in which I register beans:

```
@Service
class DummyClass {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var applicationContext: GenericWebApplicationContext

    fun dummyFunc(cluster: ElasticsearchCluster) {
        val context = SnapshotContext(cluster)
        applicationContext.registerBean("${cluster.getName()}SnapshotStartTime", Long::class, { System.nanoTime() })
        applicationContext.registerBean("${cluster.getName()}SnapshotContext", SnapshotContext::class, { context })
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing it this way instead of a `@Bean` annotation on functions in a `@Configuration` class?

Comment: To my knowledge, this method doesn't exactly fit the situation. I am trying to pass model class instances (like POJO's) as constructor parameters to another class which is annotated with `@Component`. I will have many of these POJO instances at runtime, each may be passed to that class, meaning that the other class is a helper class defined by POJO's passed as constructor parameter. The best way I found to pass these instances is named bean registration. I may be very wrong. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to add `Supplier` at the beginning of callbacks and add `.java` at the end of `::class` like the following:

```
applicationContext.registerBean("${cluster.getName()}SnapshotStartTime", Long::class.java, Supplier { System.nanoTime() })
applicationContext.registerBean("${cluster.getName()}SnapshotContext", SnapshotContext::class.java, Supplier { context })
```